# Power Pivot Report Slow

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, msdn

I wanted to see if anyone can assist. I have been using power pivot a fair amount over the last 2 years. I have created a report within it which uses 9 columns measuring 3 metrics. (Essentially sales over the last 2 years with a variance).
The Pivot table pulling through uses no sub-totals and is in tabular form pulling from only the one source file which is an excel workbook.

The issue I am receiving when I pulled in the 6th to 9th column the query got notably slower. Now taking up to 15 minutes to simply add a filter.

Can anyone assist in making this data refresh at a normal rate? I have tried making the source file smaller, making it now so that there is only one source file and not 3 however this seems to have a minimal effect.

I have other reports with much larger amounts of data and more connections where I am not encountering this problem at all so this is a little beyond my comprehension.

Comment: how many rows do you have in your powerpivot table. How many rows are you returning in the excel pivot table?

Comment: @WimV There is 16677 rows within the Pivot table generated from PowerPivot. This is because the the 3 Metrics values are in the Rows rather than columns. So in total it returns 5559 entries (currently, as this can change day to day). The Data Source itself is only 32189 rows. It was close to double that before I had to start thinking of ways to make it quicker. Another report I run the data source is Approx 400000 and It is refreshed in 5 seconds. So I am confident that its not an issue with data source.

Comment: which dax formula's are you using?

Comment: Just a couple of simple Sales 2017:=Calculate(sum(Sales[Gross]),Sales[Year]=2017). The same for 2018 and a variance which is simply [Sales 2018]-[Sales 2017].